# .htacces rewriterule to redirect if .exe/.zip

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write RewriteRule to redirect www.myweb.com/download/blabla.zip to > www.myweb.com/download/download.php?filedownload=blabla.zip

this is my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /download/
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ download.php?filedownload=$1 [L]
```

the .htaccess located in the folder /download
and the download.php file located also in the folder /download

but it doesnt work, no idea why...
Can you help me?

BTW: the mod_rewrite is enabled.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you don't need RewriteBase. And what means "it doen't work"?

Comment: I do need the rewrite base because the download folder ins inside the main folder. and "doest work" = if the $1 = test.zip, I got file that called test.zip in the folder /download so It automatcily go to www.myweb.com/download/test.zip instead www.myweb.com/download/download.php?filedownload=test.zip

Comment: RewriteBase is not needed for this. RewriteBase has another function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your RewriteRule is recursing on itself, and passing download.php as the parameter to itself.

You can try either of the following.

To match only zip/exe:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(zip|exe))$ download.php?filedownload=$1 [L]
```

To exclude download.php from matches, place this before your RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !download.php
```

Comment: Works. Thanks! (do I have to use (zip|exe), because maybe in the future I will also have different formats)

Comment: Well you can add other formats to the list, or maybe try `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !download.php` before `RewriteRule` to exclude it from any matches.